# Change color TextField to response a button color

Tags: ios, swift, text, colors

guys I have to change the color of the TextField when I press on a color of my collectionView. I'm trying with this code but it does not change anything. what am I doing wrong?

sampleTextField is inserted in a view "labelV"

```
    let sampleTextField =  UITextField()

    sampleTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "text",
                                                               attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
    sampleTextField.textColor = UIColor.white
    sampleTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.no
    sampleTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
    sampleTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    sampleTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextField.ViewMode.whileEditing;
    sampleTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControl.ContentVerticalAlignment.center
    sampleTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    debugPrint("sucaaaa")
    var cell = delegate2?.labelV.sampleTextField.textColor?.cgColor
    cell = datasource[indexPath.item].color as! CGColor

}



    var labelV: LabelView = LabelView(frame: .zero, name: "tipo")
```

[image]

Comment: Where is sampleTextfield located? And how is connected with collection view?

Comment: @DionizB sampleTextfield are located in another class, the call with "labelV"

Comment: This view is parent or child of the view that holds collectionView?

Comment: It's a bit of an indirect way of assigning a color to a textfield. For as far as I'm aware cgColor is a value type. So now you are just creating a copy that you then give a different value, but none of this will reflect in your textfield. Why don't you just assign the color property of the textfield directly?

Comment: @DionizB labelV is the parent of sampleTextField, collection view are parent of another classes who which is declared in the same class of labelV. I have: 
- CoreView content: Collectionview and labelV
-labelV who are sampleTextField

Comment: @PhilipDeVries you intend to assign "indexPath" directly to the sampleTextfield?

Comment: I mean it's not the prettiest way to do it. But delegate2?.labelV.sampleTextField.textColor = UIColor(cgColor: datasource[indexPath.item].color) should work assuming color is a cgColor

Comment: @PhilipDeVries I update image with your last solution but not work..

Comment: Try this `labelV.sampleTextField.textColor = datasource[indexPath.item].color`

Comment: Is the delegate set correctly (not nil). And is the color property returning the correct color?

Comment: @DionizB collectionView UICollectionView 0x000000010b023800
UIKit.UIScrollView UIScrollView 
indexPath IndexPath 2 indices 
_indexes IndexPath.Storage pair
self babysticky.CollectionColor 0x0000000109b0f8c0
UIKit.UIViewController UIViewController 
delegate CollectionColorDelegate? nil none
delegate2 babysticky.CoreSceneView? nil none
collectionView UICollectionView? 0x000000010b023800
cellSpacing CGFloat 1 
indexPath IndexPath 2 indices 
datasource [babysticky.CollectionColor.ColorRound] 20 values 
imageArray [UIImageView] 0 values 
onceOnly Bool true 
cell CGColor? nil none

Comment: @PhilipDeVries I do not know, I not check.. how can I debug? 
debugPrint datasource[indexpath?

Comment: you can print (delegate2) and print(datasource[indexPath.item].color) to see what they refer to.

Comment: @PhilipDeVries delegate2 are nil and color are right.. some different for button clicked

Comment: So you need to make sure you set the delegate in the class where your collection view methods are and it should work

Comment: @PhilipDeVries not work     weak var delegate2 : CoreSceneView?

Comment: Without knowing the structure of your program it's hard to help. Somewhere you will have to set delegate2 to ensure it's linking to the CoreSceneView

Comment: @PhilipDeVries     weak var delegate2 : CoreSceneView?
I connected it this way. otherwise I could not recall "labelV" ..

Comment: @PhilipDeVries how can I do ?